# Airflow pass python value with xcom from dag1 to another dag2

Tags: airflow

I'm in need of help to pass a string value from one dag to another on Airflow.
Example: I have dag1 that I pass the name parameter of a generated instance as path = "db-instance-filename1"
how can i read this value in the dag2 and get this variable to reuse in task that need to create a folder.
Thanks

Comment: Does this help you out?
https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-passing-data-between-tasks/

Comment: Do you want to share a common input to two DAGs (i.e: you know the value and can pass it down to both) or get the output of a task in `dag1` from another task in `dag2`?

Comment: @EDG956 I will need to know the output from value dag 1 and can pass it down to dag 2 the same value